# MySQL Formating Strings or Returning Empty string on NULL

Tags: mysql, string, null

I am exporting a `SELECT result to CSV via INTO OUTFILE`. I have a series of simple SQL string functions I use to format the data.  For instance: `CONCAT('$',FORMAT(property.price,2))`. I would like to otherwise return an empty string if the value is NULL, but I am unsure how to do both at the same time.

Also I am wondering the easiest way to take a `TinyInt` value of 0 or 1 and return "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tinyint you can use IF operator

```
select if(tinyint_value,'yes','no')
```

for first part you also can use if operator

```
select if(property.price is not null, CONCAT('$',FORMAT(property.price,2)),'')
```

Answer (score 1):

To return `yes`, `no` or empty string depending on he value of the column you can use case as so:

```
select case column when 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as columalias ,
       case when stringcolumn is NULL then '' else stringcolumn end as stringcolumn
from table
```

or

```
select case column when 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as columalias ,
       IFNULL(stringcolumn,'') as stringcolumn
from table
```

Comment: `case stringcolumn when NULL ...`  will not work. It should be `case WHEN stringcolumn IS NULL THEN ...`.

Comment: thanks, using if is a little more simplified for what I am doing, but I can see where this can be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [coalesce()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function. It returns the first of its arguments that's not NULL.

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 1);
-> 1
SELECT COALESCE(2, 1);
-> 2
```